# MVC5 - issues sending form parameters to controller

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm pretty new to this, so I apologise if I'm missing something obvious.

I'm trying to send two string values to a controller using Html.BeginForm.

Here's the controller code (within 'BlogsController'):

```
[Route("{type}/{variable}")]
public ActionResult BlogResult(string type, string variable)
{
}
```

I'm trying to send a 'hidden' parameter as 'type' (so that I recognise what sort of query is being performed by the user - in this case the string is 'k') and a 'text box' string as 'variable'. Here's the form in Razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BlogResult", "Blogs", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.Hidden("type", "k")
@Html.TextBox("variable")
<input type="submit" name="Submit Keyword" />
}
```

However, when the submit button is pressed, it just appears to refresh the current page and doesn't call the proper controller.

I've had a thorough search through various websites but I cannot find a satisfactory solution. Therefore, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What Model class are you binding to your view?

Comment: Are you using a model? If so use @Html.TextBoxFor()

Comment: Is the method you have shown decorated with `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: At the moment I'm not using a model in this part - I'm interacting with a model in the action method (not shown) by using the keyword in LINQ. I have other ActionLinks for different types of search (i.e. by year or by author) where the 'type' variable returns a different letter.

Comment: Have tried [HttpPost] on the method but that doesn't appear to work.

If I try:

    @using (Html.BeginForm("BlogResult", "Blogs", new { type = "y", variable = "xxxx"},FormMethod.Post))

...it does work but then, of course, I'm sending static data...

Comment: @MathCharlton, You need 2 methods for `BlogResult`, a `[HttpGet]` and a `[HttpPost]` because you have specified `FormMethod.Post`. And remove the `[Route("{type}/{variable}")]` attribute.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Cheers for that. I've just tried that and various combinations thereof and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried since clearly you have an mistake in your code, but if this is some kind of 'search' form, then it should be `FormMethod.Get` in the view anyway.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - ok. I've amended the [Route...] above the method to [HttpGet] and changed the FormMehod to 'Get' in the razor code. I've also done the same with 'Post'.

With 'Get', it adds the variables to the url as 'localhost/blog/search?type=k&variable=xxx&Submit+Keyword=Submit+Query' but the route for blog/search invokes another method.

Could this all be down to routing above methods?

Comment: @MathCharlton, Too hard to read in the comments - best to update you question with the code and routes. Note the reason that you get `Submit+Keyword=...` is because you gave the submit button a `name` attribute so it posts as well (suggest you just remove it)

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be in the rout mapping. You should use it to specify a dynamic route. ES:

```
[Route("blog/{articleId}")]
public ActionResult GetArticle(int articleId) { ... }
```

Probably when you create the form the dynamic values are still not there (you are creating them later).
Try and remove the route attribute for now and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've tried it without the route mapping and, unfortunately, it still fails to use the action method.

Comment: can you post the html resulting from that view?

Comment: This is the source code before and after button is pressed:

    <form action="" method="post">
    <input id="type" name="type" type="hidden" value="k" />
    <input id="variable" name="variable" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit Keyword" />
    </form>

Comment: Ok, apparently it just can't find the correct controller and method (action property in form tag is empty). Can you post the full controller? And try decorating your action with [HttpPost] attribute

Comment: Ok, first of all definitely delete that Route attribute. You put it when you want to map a special route for your action, which is not the case here. Second I did a test with your code and it works fine (without the Route attribute).

Comment: Moreover RoutePrefix attribute applies only to WebApi

Answer (score 0):

The form post now works as required after changing my route mapping.

I was using:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

for defining attribute routes, so I decided to comment this out and restore the default code in RouteConfig. The form then posted the correct data to the correct action method. As such, this has to be an issue with my customised attribute routes.

Thanks for all your suggestions and help.